# Renaming a column name in an SQL SELECT statement, using AS, fails when used inside of a sql:query tag; why? JSTL 1.2

Tags: sql, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jstl

I have been bashing my head against a wall all morning trying to figure this one out.

I'm upgrading a very old application and I'm having trouble with the queries in the JSP pages. (I know, I know...)

I have this query within an <sql:query> tag:

```
SELECT t1.item AS i1, t2.item AS i2 FROM table t1, table t2
```

In the JSP page, I iterate over the result set and display information.  However, `i1` and `i2` don't exist in the result set, but `item` and `item` do exist.  It appears that the renaming of the column, using the `AS` syntax, is failing.  Does anyone know why?

I'm using JSTL 1.2.  I have both the `api` and `impl` jars in my library.  I'm using a JSP 2.1, Servlet 2.5 servlet container (Tomcat 6, to be exact).  I'm using the (as far as I know) correct namespaces for this version of JSTL (`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`,
`<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>`).

The above query functions properly when used in a JSP 2.0, Servlet 2.4 servlet container (Tomcat 5).  I'm not sure of the version of JSTL it uses.

The query runs fine when I run it within MySQL Workbench, too.

Comment: Is that the whole query? Do you really intend to do a cross join?

Comment: I've never used JSTL SQL taglib extensively, so I can't tell from experience. All I can suggest is to try downgrading to [JSTL 1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) because it seemed to work fine on your previous Servlet 2.4 container. JSTL 1.1 should work as good on Servlet 2.5.

Comment: @Icarus, It's just an example.  Even "SELECT item AS i FROM table" fails.

Comment: I took the jstl and standard jars from Tomcat 5 and used them in Tomcat 6.  Still a no go!  :(

Comment: And you removed the JSTL 1.2 libs? That's plain weird then. Did you also change the JDBC driver version?

Comment: @cogaritis Not sure if this is the issue 

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33561

Comment: @BalusC Aye, I removed the 1.2 libs.  I tested this by only using the jstl.jar and it blew up requiring the standard.jar (which is required by 1.1, but not by 1.2 afaik).  I tried two different JDBC drivers - one that the Tomcat 5 server is using, and one that I'm using in other applications.

Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @r0ast3d Interesting!  I'll look more into that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @r0ast3d's suggestion:

"[29 Dec 2007 0:16] Mark Matthews

For many sane reasons, the JDBC experts' group clarified the meaning of "column name" to
mean original column name, not the alias (which can be retrieved via the getColumnLabel()
method of ResultSetMetaData), therefore our JDBC driver uses this definition when mapping
from "name" to column ordinal in ResultSet.get*(String).

You can revert to the old behavior by setting the configuration property
"useOldAliasMetadataBehavior" to "true" with our JDBC driver, but applications (and
frameworks) really should be changed to support the behavior."

The culprit was the JDBC driver.